# Printing Nth item in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to Create a function that returns the Nth in a list of numbers or words. I would like to keep it simple with out importing anything, I am trying to figure this out for learning purposes, several examples are welcome, thanks!

```
def printNth(lst,n):
    lst=[]
    for i in lst:
        if i>=0:
            if i%n!=0:
                print(i)
```

Right now for a number list I get the output I want example:

```
printNth([1,2,3,4,5,6],2)
1
3
5
```

I am having trouble with getting it to work with words.

Example of what I would like it to do:

```
printNth(['apple','pear','oj','banana'],2)
'apple'
'pear'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `lst=[]`, completely ignoring the `lst` that was passed in.

Remove this nonsensical line.

Also, `for i in lst` iterates over all of the *items* in the list.  If you want to iterate over the items *and* their index, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
def printNth(lst, n):
    for idx,item in enumerate(lst):
        if (idx % n) != 0:
            print(item)
```

---

A better idea would be to instead make a function that returns every nth item. This is where *generators* come in handy:

```
def every_nth(lst, n):
    for idx,item in enumerate(lst):
        if (idx % n) != 0:
            yield item

for item in every_nth(['apple','pear','oj','banana'], 2):
    print item
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have a bad habit of doing lst=[]. Thanks for calling me out on it!